# Can you really not move between grapples/shoves?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, actions, attack, grapple

The rule on [moving between attacks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MovingBetweenAttacks) specifically says:

> If you take an action that includes more than one weapon attack, you can break up your movement even further by moving between those attacks.

So, with a strict reading of the rules, what happens if you take an action that includes only grapples and shoves, which are [not weapon attacks](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/07/11/are-grapple-and-shove-melee-weapon-attacks/)? Does this really prevent you from moving between them?

For example, if a Fighter with Extra Attack wanted to use it to make multiple attacks, but both (or even one) of them was planned to be a shove/grapple. Would they not be able to move between the grapples/shoves because they are not taking an action which "includes more than one weapon attack"?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### You gain the ability to split your move before you decide to grapple/shove

The sections on [grappling and shoving](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Grappling) both include the sentence:

> If you're able to make multiple attacks with the Attack action, this attack replaces one of them.

So, if you have the Extra Attack feature, in order to make a grapple attack, you take the Attack action, which includes multiple weapon attacks, and then you *replace* one or more of those weapon attacks. But since you've already "taken an action that includes more than one weapon attack", you can move between those attacks. Or to put it another way, **you gain the ability to split your move between attacks when you take the Attack action, before making (or not making) any weapon attacks.** This ability can't possibly depend on whether you *actually* end up making multiple weapon attacks with your action, because that isn't determined until your action is complete. Any number of things could happen during your action to prevent you from making multiple weapon attacks: you could replace some or all of your weapon attacks with grapple/shove attempts; you could get pushed out of range by a readied *Thunderwave*; or you could lose one or more attacks entirely to a *Sanctuary* spell. But regardless of what happens, you can't retroactively lose the ability to split your movement between attacks.

This is similar to the logic that allows spells like *Shield* to work: the trigger for the spell is being hit with an attack, but the spell causes the attack to miss, which means the spell works even though it prevented its trigger from happening. Likewise, replacing some of the weapon attacks from the Attack action doesn't change the fact that it was initially an Attack action that included multiple weapon attacks.

#### A concrete example

For a concrete example of why this must be the case, let's consider the example given in the section on moving between attacks:

> a fighter who can make two attacks with the Extra Attack feature and who has a speed of 25 feet could move 10 feet, make an attack, move 15 feet, and then attack again.

Suppose the fighter chose to replace their *second* weapon attack with a shove attack, *after* they have already split their movement between the two attacks. Their Attack action now involves only one weapon attack. Does this invalidate or undo the split move that got them to the second creature? I don't think so. The decision of whether to replace an attack comes *after* the decision to take the Attack action, and in this case it even comes after the decision to split movement between weapon attacks. So it doesn't make sense that your available choices in an earlier decision (splitting your move) can be constrained by a choice you only make later (replacing an attack). The most logical conclusion is that the ability to split movement between weapon attacks is "unlocked" as soon as you take the Attack action and remains so throughout that action, whether or not you *actually* end up making multiple weapon attacks.

Comment: @Akixkisu Attacks using weapons are weapon attacks, and unarmed strikes are also technically weapon attacks. What other type of attack can you make with the Attack action that isn't a weapon attack (other than grapple/shove attacks)?

Comment: @Akixkisu From the Attack section, PHB page 192 “The most common action to take in combat is the Attack action, whether you are swinging a sword, firing an arrow from a bow, or brawling with your fists.” This strongly implies you are making an attack *with a weapon* considering all of those are on the Weapons Table. Also, Spell Attacks are noticeably absent from the Making An Attack section.

Comment: I think that additional section may have convinced me. Great addition!

Comment: I agree, pretty much any attack action OTHER than casting a spell or using a spell attack should count as allowing you to split your movement -- I'd even allow Shoving and grappling, as long as they were distinct actions e.g. you shove opponent one and then grapple opponent two (also you couldn't grapple more than one opponent at a time -- though I'd allow multiple grapple attempts/menuvers against the same target )

Answer (score 3):

#### No movement in between

> Moving between Attacks:
> If you take an action that includes more than one weapon attack, you can break up your movement even further by moving between those attacks. For example, a fighter who can make two attacks with the Extra Attack feature and who has a speed of 25 feet could move 10 feet, make an attack, move 15 feet, and then attack again.

Key phrase “**If you take an action that includes more than one weapon attack**”. Grappling and Shoving are not considered a weapon attack. Though the Extra Attack feature would still allow you to grapple/shove/attack, just not move.

Shoving

> Using the Attack action, you can make a special melee attack to shove a creature, either to knock it prone or push it away from you. If you’re able to make multiple attacks with the Attack action, this attack replaces one of them

**But**

If would be able to move between your Attack Action, Bonus Action, and possible Action Surge. Also an 11th level Fighter gains their 2nd Extra Attack.  As long as more than one attack is a weapon attack, movement is allowed.

Comment: I think Medix was asking about a character that has 2 attacks per attack action. Not a character that uses action surge.

Comment: Feels like this really needs an errata.

Comment: @NautArch I agree